# why this shader crashes

Tags: android, opengl-es

```html
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D uTexture;
varying vec2 vCoordinate;
uniform float uAlpha;
varying vec4 vColor;

void main(){
    vec4 color=texture2D(uTexture,vCoordinate);
    color.a *= uAlpha;
        color.r = 1.0;
        color.g = 1.0;
        color.b = 1.0;
        color.a = 1.0;
    gl_FragColor=color;
//    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
```

it crashed where I'm drawing a plane, but if I use this frag.shader to a sphere.it works well.

Comment: I just want to set a color to my objects when user pass a color instead of a bitmap texture.

Comment: Please complete your question instead of adding more information in the comments.

Comment: Think you need to clarify what you mean by the shader crashing. My guess is that by overwriting all components of `color` you're allowing the driver to optimize away your uniforms (`uAlpha` and `uTexture`). My guess is that your CPU code assumes that those uniforms exist and that you're crashing on the CPU due to those assumptions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.